# uiimage is going to null when flipping pages of uipageviewcontroller and memory warning issue due to uiimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

i am facing that issue and could not find any solution.. when i flip nearly 123 pages then image will be nil and application crashes.kindly help me.here is the code which i am using to load image which is in my project sources and adding that image in NSMutableArray pageContent

```
   NSString* fileName = [[_imageNameArr objectAtIndex:currentPageIndex]stringByDeletingPathExtension];    
NSString *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"png"];    
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:paths];

//i had already tried to empty NSMutableArray but issue did not resolved
/*[pageContent removeAllObjects];
 pageContent = nil;
 pageContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:emptyStringsArr];*/

[pageContent replaceObjectAtIndex:currentPageIndex withObject:img];
```

following is my crash log

```
2014-05-08 11:30:16.465 myProject[297:60b] image = (null)
2014-05-08 11:30:16.466 myProject[297:60b] imageNameArr object = 124.png
2014-05-08 11:30:16.468 myProject[297:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception         'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x309d0f4b 0x3ace56af 0x3090bf83 0x151245 0x151bff 0x33612547 0x33612e03 0x332c9b65       0x33173b1d 0x331732df 0x33172dbf 0x3314879d 0x33146fa3 0x3099c183 0x3099b653 0x30999e47 0x30904c27 0x30904a0b 0x355f4283 0x331a8049 0x20b62d 0x3b1edab7)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you post crash log? Code above is seems to be fine.

Comment: i have posted the crash log

Comment: Have you noticed that you're assigning the image in the variable **img** and then replacing the object in the array with the variable **_img**, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here..`[pageContent replaceObjectAtIndex:currentPageIndex withObject:_img];` `_img` is nil, you cann't replace object with nil. Just check and replace as below

```
if (_img != nil)
   [pageContent replaceObjectAtIndex:currentPageIndex withObject:_img];
```

Comment: i had used that check before..but if _img is nil then which image i will display on the page ? i tried to allocate again image when it is nil but did not worked..

Comment: Just add Dummy image with bundle, content as Image Not Display as like, If image is nil, just show that image. Don't allocate new image... Or if Image is nil, just restrict page view controller cann't be scroll. That's just `nextViewController` delegate method will return nil in this case...

Comment: ok..but i dont know why image is going nil while it exists here in my project

Comment: What is `_img`? why didn't use `img`[UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:paths];]?

Comment: i think array is holding reference of images therefor memory is leaking..could i release image or array while using ARC ?

Comment: No. You cann't use release method while using ARC.

Comment: previously i had used UIImage *img but i found the same result

Comment: it is actually img not _img.. my mistake during edditing question..could you please suggest any solution why memory is leaking..due to image or array ?

Comment: what is your problem here? Memory leak or crash which you've mentioned above?

Comment: crash due to memory leakage

Comment: yes now it is not giving memory warning..only crash when i reached on nearly 124 page by flipping pages.

Comment: img is nil and when it replaces it is crashed..i am stuck that why image is going nil..

Comment: Did you add 124.png with project file ? Double check with name whether  space or any spl character added with that which also lead to this error. or change that image and check..

Comment: i have briefly checked the images names these are correct.. image becomes nil sometimes on 124, 125, 126, 127 .. and it occures when i continueosly flip the pages..if i go to some page directly by selecting page number then it is fine..issue is on flipping

Comment: May  8 14:51:42 Iphone myProject[564] <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed '/var/mobile/Applications/B45D7641-EAD2-4F15-851C-AC8DE93BCE50/myProject.app/127.png'